# Helper method for testing JsonResult in Nunit

Tags: c#, nunit, jsonresult

Here is my controller that returns a JSON.

```
public JsonResult GetValues()
{
    return Json(
    new{
        title = new {
            text = "Hello World"
        },
        xAxis = new {
            type = "List of countries"
            labels = new {
                rotation = 90
            }
        }
    },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And in my Nunit, i am testing as follows:

```
  [Test]
    public void TestGetValues()
    {
        var controller = new HelloWorldController();
        var values = controller.GetValues() as JsonResult;

        Assert.IsNotNull(data);
        var title = values.Data.GetType().GetProperty("title")
                    .GetValue(values.Data,null);
        var text = title.GetType().GetProperty("text").GetValue(title);
        Assert.IsNotNull(text);

    }
```

This works fine but i have to test several methods that has same properties which will require me to write same thing over and over again. How to write a helper method so that i can just pass in the controller and the property i want to test. 
Something like this:

```
var checkText = GetJSonProperties(controllername, "data/title/text");
var checkXais = GetJSonProperties(controllernmae, "data/xAxis/Type");
```

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a dynamic type.

```
var controller = new HelloWorldController();
dynamic values = controller.GetValues();

var title = (string)values.title;
```

Saves you writing helper methods, which themselves may need to be tested!

Comment: I have already tried that method but i cannot access the properties in that way. It gives me the error "object' does not contain a definition for 'title'" I have also made it visible.
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("HelloWorldTests.dll")]

any idea what i might be doing wrongly ?

Comment: I assume you're using an MVC controller and not a WebApi controller, right?